# what is the subproblem here and how it is being calculated

Tags: dynamic-programming

N exams numbered from 1 to N are going be held at Geekland state university. Geek is a renowned professor at the university and therefore is given the task to design the datesheet for exams. Datesheet must be made in such a way that total number of holidays in the datesheet is exactly K i.e. sum of holidays given for each exam is exactly K. Moreover, no exam should have more than M holidays. Two datesheets are considered different if number of holidays for a particular exam in both the datesheets is different. Find number of valid datesheets Geek can choose from. As answer can be very large, find it modulo 10^9 + 7.

solution:
int datesheets(int N, int K, int M){

```
    int mod = 1000000007;
    vector<vector<int>> dp(N+1, vector<int>(K+1, 0));
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        dp[i][0] = 1;
        
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= K; j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] += dp[i-1][j];
            dp[i][j] %= mod;
            
            dp[i][j] += dp[i][j-1];
            dp[i][j] %= mod;
            
            if(j-M>0)
            {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i][j] - dp[i-1][j-M-1] + mod;
                dp[i][j] %= mod;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return dp[N][K];
}
```